# Cannot compile Ada Web Server AWS hello_world application

Tags: ada

**SYSTEM CONFIGURATION:**

- Linux 3.19 (Mint)
- GPS Version: GPS 2016 (20160515) hosted on i686-pc-linux-gnu
  GNAT 4.6

**INSTALLED PACKAGES:**

- libaws-bin
- libaws-dbg
- libaws2.10.2
- libaws2.10.2-dev
- gnat-gps
- gnat-gps-common
- gnat-4.6
- gnat-4.6-base
- gnat-4.8-base
- gnat

**TROUBLE DESCRIPTION:**

I'm seeing the following error message when trying to compile the aws_hello_world project using GNAT Programming Studio (GPS):

Error text: default.gpr:2:6 unkown project file: "aws"

**default.gpr**

```
with "aws"; -- This is the line with the error --

project Default is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Exec_Dir use ".";

   for Main use ("default-main.adb");

   package Builder is
      for Executable ("default-main.adb") use "default";
   end Builder;

   package Compiler is
      for Switches ("Ada") use ("-gnat05");
   end Compiler;

end Default;
```

Attempting to build the project using the command line also fails:

```
ada_n00b@wasted_planet ~/Desktop/aws_hello_world $ gprbuild
using project file default.gpr
Error: no native compiler found for language 'ada', default runtime 
default.gpr:2:06: unknown project file: "aws"
gprbuild: "default.gpr" processing failed
```

Any help on getting this to build would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The AdaCore suite AWS has nothing to do with Amazon Web Services, so I removed the tag

Comment: I assumed that AWS stood for Ada Web Server. Actually, it's ambiguous.

Comment: gprbuild can be picky about compiler versions; if it’s looking for 4.6 (you say you have GNAT 4.6) but only finds 4.8 (you say you have gnat-4.8-base) it may refuse to play.

Comment: @Johnson It's not ambiguous; the descriptions of tags you could select when creating your question are displayed automatically. Reading them would have immediately clued you in that it was the wrong tag.

Comment: In a perfect world, yes. But annoyingly there are other languages out there, and people who use them tend to appropriate Ada community project names with impunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to install the GNAT GPL compiler from AdaCore and use it to build Ada Web Server.

I was using the FSF GNAT available in the Debian package repositories. Ada Web Server does not build "out-of-the-box" with FSF GNAT.

Comment: I highly doubt its completely incompatible. It is quite likely to be less plug-and-play though.

Comment: I've amplified the precision of my answer in regards to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get on the command line reveals your mistake:

```
Error: no native compiler found for language 'ada', default runtime
```

You may want to install the package `gnat` on your build system.

Comment: @Johnson: Add `/usr/local/gnat` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Johnson You may want to update the question then.  `gnat` is not on your list of installed Ubuntu packages.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen the question has been updated now